# Excel loses link to ODBC data (Sql)

Tags: sql, excel, odbc

We are using Excel to query a SQL database and we have multiple queries in one workbook.

Every now and then (and on different users) a spreadsheet will come up with an error and lose some of its connections although not necessarily all of them.
So on a 25 sheet/query workbook it may lose the last 5 sheets links and flatfile them.

Does anyone know what may cause this or what we can do to stop it happening?

It does not happen all the time which makes it even more frustrating !

Comment: Can you provide the error, version of Excel, and the details of the SQL connection?

Comment: From memory.... Excel 2010, the error was that some data had been lost I think when opening the spreadsheet or sometimes just when refreshing the spreadsheet (sorry for being vague) and the SQL connection is an ODBC connection  to a SQL server. We have many identical connections which work fine.

Comment: It is going to be virtually impossible to debug this without knowing the error; more specifically, the ODBC error that is occurring.  Can you generate an ODBC Trace log and provide the error that is occurring from that or, if possible, provide the trace file itself?